# how to disable row selection of checkboxmodel of grid keeping previously selection intact extjs

Tags: extjs, grid

I am unable keep selection after locking model of grid. My code is as below.

```
var sm = Ext.getCmp('loadFrameStateInfoTable').getSelectionModel(); // This select the rows which I want to
var stateStore = sm.store;
for (var ct in frameInfo) {
    var cd = frameInfo[ct].state_code;
    if (frameInfo[ct].st_flag == 'Y') {
        var index1 = stateStore.find('state_cd', cd);
        Ext.getCmp('loadFrameStateInfoTable').getSelectionModel().select(index1, true);
    }
}

// This lock the checkbox model
var sm = Ext.getCmp('loadFrameStateInfoTable').getSelectionModel();
if (frame_status == 'Pending' || frame_status == 'Failed' || frame_status == 'Generated') {

} else {
    Ext.getCmp('update_button').disabled = true;
    sm.setLocked(true);
}
```